# JsonPath : how to dynamically cast and map result

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Is there any possibility to map `JsonPath.read(...)` result and cast based on passing type as an argument or something like that?
I have json that contains any type of field, I don't know how to do that casting and mapping.

```
String json="{\r\n  \"array\": [\r\n    1,\r\n    2,\r\n    3\r\n  ],\r\n  \"boolean\": true,\r\n  \"color\": \"gold\",\r\n  \"null\": null,\r\n  \"number\": 123,\r\n  \"object\": {\r\n    \"a\": \"b\",\r\n    \"c\": \"d\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"string\": \"Hello World\",\r\n  \"test\": {\r\n    \"test2\": {\r\n      \"test3\": \"hello\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"test2\": {\r\n    \"test2\": {\r\n      \"test3\": \"hello\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"teststring\": \"{\\\"test1\\\":\\\"abc\\\"}\"\r\n}";
            
String str =  (String)JsonPath.read(json, "$.['test']");//java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**Excepted result:**

```
{"test2": {"test3": "hello"}
```

I am planning to use the result as SQL query column so based on result column type will create.

**for example**

In the above json key is `test` that is JsonObject so return result and type expected either JsonObject type or String type.
`color` is String so return type expected String in cast.
And so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case? By ` any type of fields` do you mean, `test` can be a `JsonObject`, `JsonArray` or a simple `Value`? Also what is that you are planning to do with the output?

Comment: any type of field means based on json  provided path in above case ```test``` that means it either string or jsonobject.and if take other path ```$.boolean``` type expected boolean same for other path in json

Comment: How about using Jackson? Here is the reference https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object

Comment: looking for in JsonPath itself any configuration or mapping possibility something like  ```return JsonPath.read_or_other_method (json,path,mapping,returntype)``` etc as mention in question